# Bootstrap responsive not centering elements below 482px

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

A simple page which I've designed with bootstrap framework stops becoming responsive once the screen width is below 482px? The only thing i can spot is that it stops adjusting elements once the screen reaches the width of the form input fields plus an equal amount of padding either side, thus i suspect that the issue is somehow related to the form input field width settings, but I am unsure. Can anyone help please? I have read the documentation yet i am none the wiser regarding a solution.

Here's my bootply: http://www.bootply.com/DLxLacH4Jy#

Comment: It shouldn't "stop" being responsive, rather there are no break point below 767px. As suggested by @yuyokk below, you simple need to add an additional media query if you want to make adjustments at a smaller screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the specific problem I was having in my example was that i had over complicated the form with bootstrap grid classes for screen size formats, e.g. .col-xs-4 /col-md-6 etc, this had disrupted the inline form display and in trying to override this, not quite understanding what was negating the inline display, I used a width class to set a width of the inline form, this was stopping the responsiveness below the set width of the inline form elements.

Cleaned and corrected code here; http://www.bootply.com/DLxLacH4Jy

I've taken the liberty of adding this as my own answer to the question, as it does represent the solution to the exact problem i was trying to solve, however both Yuyokk & Joe Conlin's comments above were directly relevant and helpful also, if not the precise solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has the following breakpoints

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {}
@media (min-width: 768px) {}
@media (min-width: 992px) {}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

So if you want to apply some specific styles for screens smaller then 482px
all you have to do is to write class like

```
@media (max-width: 482px) {
  .class-to-center {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```